# How to resolve "Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am new in Android Studio Development. I am getting this error in my project.

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar

Here is my App Gradle **dependencies** code **(build.gradle (Module: app))**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
}
```

Here is the full error:

```
Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzq found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzr found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0) 
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
```

I am using FusedLocation Service as well as Google Ads (Admob) in my project.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

`play-services-ads:18.3.0` will pull in a rather current version, which doesn't need to be jetified.

Comment: I am using "import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi" and "FusedLocationProviderClient" in my MainActivity.java. When I remove that line as you suggested, I am getting error "cannot find symbol class GoogleApi" and "package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist".

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin add this one instead: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0`; [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) you can find all the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved when I updated the com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework library to the latest version.